# ES6 function with no parameters?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to make a function that is being called with no parameters ? for example, I have this class

```
export class Student {
  constructor(ssn) {
    this.SSN = ssn;
  }
  SocialSecurityNumber() {
    return this.SSN;
  }
}
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
let student = new Student(123456);
console.log(student.SocialSecurityNumber);
```

this doesnt work now, but is there a syntax that I can use to accomplish this ?

Comment: `student.SocialSecurityNumber()` - you need to call it, otherwise you're just printing the function definition. Also it's more common practice to start with a lowercase letter on the function name - e.g. `getSocialSecurityNumber`

Comment: To _call_ a function, you need to use parenthesis even though no params are passed. Otherwise the parser treats your code as attempt to _access_ a Function object.

Comment: You you want `student.SocialSecurityNumber` to work, do `this.SocialSecurityNumber = ssn;` and just remove the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to add that an alternative to calling the function with parenthesis `student.socialSecurityNumber()`, you could make this a getter:

```js
class Student {
  constructor(ssn) {
    this.SSN = ssn;
  }
  get socialSecurityNumber() {
    return this.SSN;
  }
}

const student = new Student(123456);
console.log(student.socialSecurityNumber);
```

That way you could call it with the same syntax as a property.

Answer (score 1):

If you are supporting Object methods, you can add object properties similar to the syntactic sugar you'd see in C#.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Basically,

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 
                      'SocialSecurityNumber',
                      {
                          get: function() { return this.SocialSecurityNumber(); }
                      }
```

inside your constructor